# Put shortcake in iframe url in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, shortcode

on Wordpress, I am trying to embed a form. There is an option to pre-fill fields, so for example:

form url:
example.com/form

then I can prefill form fields with example.com/form?test=123 (so the 123 is the profile data and test the field name).

Now I need to prefill the form using iframe on Wordpress. Can someone help.

Thanks,
Kind Regards